# How to pass arguments in lambda function in python

Tags: python, lambda

```
freq_items = dict(filter(lambda k,v : float(v)/float(self.total_items) >= self.support, items_list.items()))
```

This line is giving me error, "lambda 1 missing positional argument: v". Anyone can help me out to figure this error.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2, it is possible to fix your program with argument tuple unpacking:

```
freq_items = dict(filter(lambda (k,v) : float(v)/float(self.total_items) >= self.support, items_list.items()))
```

This was removed in Python 3. But the following remains:

```
freq_items = dict(filter(lambda item: float(item[1])/float(self.total_items) >= self.support, items_list.items()))
```

However, you really should use a dictionary comprehension:

```
freq_items = {k:v for k,v in items_list.items() if float(v)/float(self.total_items) >= self.support}
```

Or if you prefer the `dict` constructor for 2.5 compatibility.

```
freq_items = dict(k,v for k,v in items_list.items() if float(v)/float(self.total_items) >= self.support)
```